# Software for tracking mutiple software products, revisions, artifacts and dependencies

Tags: software-development, product-management

I'm working for a company that produces about 100 applications/services/libraries/full products. I'm looking for software that would be able to keep track of those, so there will be possibility to:

1. register new product (with info like name, source code link, short description, maintainers)
2. add next revision of given product (store revision of given product with link to binary artifact)
3. create dependencies between products (for example, given service uses x internal libraries)
4. comunicate with this portal via REST or some CLI app.
   browse throught products and it's revisions with some web interface.
5. Setting custom labels for given product revision (like marking if that revision passed some specific tests)

Important thing here is that tool is not for managing binary artifacts itself.
So basically, it's more database oriented tool. Any ideas? I tried googling, but I only got some product managment tools for project managers with charts etc. Not software-binary-database oriented.

Preferably it should run on Linux. If it comes to price, open-source is my goal, but with no alternatives, paid solutions come to play.